# For loop and find command

Tags: windows, batch

I'd like to parse out only the line number of find command. Here is my attempt:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=[" %a IN ('find /n "string" 2.txt') DO @ECHO %a
```

but it returns sth. like that:

```
---------- 2.TXT
2]string
```

instead of just:

```
---------- 2.TXT
```

When i change the delimiter to ] -it's ok - the %a contains:

```
---------- 2.TXT
[2
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
FIND
Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.

Syntax
      FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] "string" [pathname(s)]

Key
   "string"    The text string to find (must be in quotes).

   [pathname]  A drive/file(s) to search (wildcards accepted).

  ⇉  /V        Display all lines NOT containing the specified string.

     /C        Count the number of lines containing the string.

     /N        Display Line numbers.

     /I        Ignore the case of characters when searching for the string.

  [/off[line]] Do not skip files that have the offline attribute set.
```

---

**1.** You do not need to define the delimiter as **`"["`** or **`"]"`**

```bat
> for /f delims^= %a IN ('find/n "string" 2.txt^|find/v "["')do @echo=%a
```

**Obs.:** Use one space in: `delims^=ESPACE%a`

**2.** Just add a **`^|find/v "["`**, to omit lines containing **`[n]`** in the output

```bat
> for /f delims^= %a IN ('find/n "string" 2.txt^|find/v "["')do @echo=%a
---------- 2.TXT
```

- To get only the file name:

```bat
> for /f tokens^=1*delims^=-^  %a IN ('find/n "string" 2.txt^|find/v "["')do @echo=%a
2.TXT
```

**Obs.:** Use two spaces in: `delims^=-^ESPACEESPACE%a`

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)